# How to remove values from raster band QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, remove

I recently did a land use land cover analysis using the semi automatic classification plugin in QGIS. While I am satisfied with the produced raster there are a bunch of classes that are not relevant but take up a lot of space, which bogs down further use of the raster. Can I remove these classes using the raster calculator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-saving the the raster file and adding "no data classes". This effectively removed them from the projection, it also sped up further analyses. I went to **export > save as** all the way at the bottom you can activate no data classes.[image]